# Reusable Cards in react MUI5

Tags: reactjs, image, material-ui, components, card

I've created a reusable card in react using MUI, and it is working quite well.

> CardComponent.js

```
import React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import { CardHeader } from "@mui/material";

const StyledCard = styled((props) => <Card {...props} />)(({ theme }) => ({
  maxWidth: 500,
  margin: "0 auto",
  marginBottom: "1rem",
  marginTop: "1rem"
}));

const CardComponent = (props) => {
  const { title, content } = props;

  return (
    <StyledCard sx={{ minWidth: 275 }} elevation={5}>

      <CardHeader title={title} />

      <CardContent>{content}</CardContent>

    </StyledCard>
  );
};

export default CardComponent;
```

> TerraGit.js

```
import * as React from "react"; import { Typography } from "@mui/material"; import CardComponent from "../../../components/reusable/CardComponent";


export default function BasicCard() {   return (
    <>
      <CardComponent

      title={<Typography variant="h2">TerraGit</Typography>}

      content={
      <Typography variant="h6">lmvlkfmvlkfvlfkmvflkmvlfkmv</Typography>
      }
      />
    </>   ); }
```

[Reusable Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IxRu.png)

This effectively displays the card as i want it. The current problem occurs when I try add media to the card.

> CardComponent.js

```
import React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import { CardHeader } from "@mui/material";
import { CardMedia } from "@mui/material";

const StyledCard = styled((props) => <Card {...props} />)(({ theme }) => ({
  maxWidth: 500,
  margin: "0 auto",
  marginBottom: "1rem",
  marginTop: "1rem"
}));

const CardComponent = (props) => {
  const { title, content } = props;

  return (
    <StyledCard sx={{ minWidth: 275 }} elevation={5}>
      
      <CardMedia component="img"
                  alt="projects"
                  height="50"
                  image={image}></CardMedia>

      <CardHeader title={title} />

      <CardContent>{content}</CardContent>
    </StyledCard>
  );
};

export default CardComponent;
```

> TerraGit.js

```
import * as React from "react";
    import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
    import CardComponent from "../../../components/reusable/CardComponent";
    import { CardMedia } from "@mui/material";
    
    
    export default function BasicCard() {
      return (
        <>
          <CardComponent
    
          image = {"../../../assets/images/TerraGitLogo.png"}
    
          title={<Typography variant="h2">TerraGit</Typography>}
    
          content={
          <Typography variant="h6">lmvlkfmvlkfvlfkmvflkmvlfkmv</Typography>
          }
          />
        </>
      );
    }
```

This returns an error which states that the image was not defined.

Could I please get some help in figuring this out? I just want to be able to rotate the Image section of the CardMedia whenever using a new card.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Good to know. Thank you. Any idea on the issue

Answer (score 0):

In your `CardComponent.js` you are not extracting the `image` attribute from `props` variable

Hence It is giving the error `image was not defined`.

To remove the error update your code accordingly in `CardComponent.js` file

```
 const { title, content, image } = props;
```